# Get AND of two Expression<Predicate<string>> objects

Tags: c#, expression, expression-trees, predicate

I need to build Expression> dynamically as conjunction of Expression> objects, e.g.

```
Expression<Predicate<string>> expression1 = c => c.Contains("aaa");
Expression<Predicate<string>> expression2 = c => c.Contains("bbb");
```

How can I combine these expressions with AND operator to obtain another

```
Expression<Predicate<string>>
```

object?

Thanks!

Comment: [What have you Tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var par = Expression.Parameter(typeof(string));
Expression<Predicate<string>> expression3 = 
    Expression.Lambda<Predicate<string>>(
        Expression.AndAlso(
            Expression.Invoke(expression1, par), 
            Expression.Invoke(expression2, par)), 
        par);

Predicate<string> method1 = expression3.Compile();
Console.WriteLine(method1("aaa"));
Console.WriteLine(method1("bbb"));
Console.WriteLine(method1("aaabbb"));
```

We have to create a new expression. `par` is the parameter. Then we use `Expression.Invoke` to invoke the "old" expressions (and passing `par` as their parameter). Then we use `Expression.AndAlso` to make the `&&` expression. Finally we use `Expression.Lambda<Predicate<string>>` to create the final expression (the last parameter, `par` is the name of the parameter of the lambda expression)

Be aware (common error) that `Expression.And` is `&`, while `Expression.AndAlso` is `&&` (the same for the `Expression.Or*`)

Answer (score 1):

You'd do basically what's done using `PredicateBuilder`, but with `Predicate` instead of the `Func<T, bool>` that it uses:

```
public static Expression<Predicate<string>> And(this Expression<Predicate<string>> expr1,
                                                Expression<Predicate<string>> expr2)
{
    var invokedExpr = Expression.Invoke(expr2, expr1.Parameters.Cast<Expression>());
    return Expression.Lambda<Predicate<string>>
            (Expression.AndAlso(expr1.Body, invokedExpr), expr1.Parameters);
}
```

If you don't mind using `Func<string, bool>` instead of `Predicate`, then you can just use [PredicateBuilder](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx) directly.

Comment: Nice way to reuse `expr1`

Answer (score 0):

```
Expression<Predicate<string>> expression1 = c => c.Contains("aaa") && c.Contains("bbb");
```

The above will work, and should always be a possibility. However, if you're trying for some reason to generically combine these predicates, try the following:

```
Expression<Predicate<string>> expression1 = c => c.Contains("aaa");
Expression<Predicate<string>> expression2 = c => c.Contains("bbb");
Expression<Predicate<string>> expression3 = Expression.AndAlso(expression1.body , expression2.body);
```

additionally, here's the documentation for it: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb353520.aspx
You will find other similarly useful members of     Expression

Comment: You are not invoking the predicates.

Comment: No, see the other answers.

Comment: Aren't you able to combine them before invoking? You should be able to wait until you have the andAlso expression before you invoke.

Comment: `Expression.AndAlso(expression1.body , expression2.body);` That won't work, because they have distinct parameters (it's like expression1 is `c => c` and expression2 is `d => d`)